# same column height with bootstrap div based table

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3 grid system to create a div based table.
Here is my code on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/iWoLewu/4/edit?output

As you see the height of product column and other column is different.

**Edit:** I don't want fixed height also I want link for entire table row except one column. please see above jsbin code first.

Thanks for your attentions.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix height like that

```
.myCell{height:80px;}
```

Of course 80px is jsut an example put the value you need/want.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want fixed height.

Comment: and why don't you use bootstrap table instead of using div ? Tables are the best to present this kind of data...

Comment: Please refer to this link <http://jsfiddle.net/hUMvw/> to add link to entire table row and you can use bootstrap tables..

Comment: this one works http://jsfiddle.net/hUMvw/ (probably a bad copy paste from Aarthi)

Comment: @DotNetWise, it works for me, when you hover the "tr" the background becomes red as expected, and it is reset to nothing when you mouse out